# Keyboard shortcut for selecting a whole chord in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

I have a Sibelius score with chords all in voice 1.

If I mouse click a single note in a chord, that single note is selected.

If I double-click a note in a chord, the entire chord is selected.

What is the equivalent keyboard shortcut with the same behaviour as double-click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac it is Cmd-Shift-A. Ctrl-Shift-A on PC. Incidentally this also selects all similar objects attached to a particular stave. For instance, it can select all dynamic markings, or hairpins attached to a single stave.

Here are some examples. Single note selected:

[image]

and after Cmd-Shift-A:

[image]

Single dynamic marking selected:

[image]

and after Cmd-Shift-A:

[image]